# Python argparse custom action with optional arguments

Tags: python, action, argparse, optional-arguments

I use the custom Actions with option + argument as below.

It works fine, but I would like 'arg1' to be optional, by submitting a default value.

```
class DumpAction(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(self, option_strings, arg1, default='config.yaml', *args, **kwargs):
        super(DumpAction, self).__init__(option_strings=option_strings, *args, **kwargs)
    
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_strings):
        print(f"Value: {values}.")

....
parser.add_argument('-d', '--dump', action=DumpAction, arg1='file')
```

Comment: What default do you want? Giving `arg1` a default value is no different than giving `default` a default value of `'config.yaml'`. (Which, by the way, you aren't passing on to `super.__init__`, because `default` isn't included in `kwargs`.)

Comment: Even if I pass `default='config.yaml'` on to `super.__init__()`, argparse returns `arparse_action.py: error: argument -d/--dump: expected one argument` if I don't specify an argument.

Comment: You get that `expected one argument` message because `nargs` is the default `None`.  Compare your `__init__` with `_StoreAction`, and `_StoreConstAction` (which sets `nargs=0` and requires a `const`), or `_StoreTrueAction` (where that `const` if predetermined).  It's probably wiser to inherit from one of the action subclasses, and only modify what you absolutely must.  The transformation from `add_argument` to `Action` creation is not trivial.